A characterization for the Riesz representation theorem vector
Let $H$ a Hilbert space and $\varphi \in H'$ a continuous linear functional. By Riesz Representation Theorem we know there exists $u_\varphi \in H$ such that
$$
\varphi(v) = \langle v, u_\varphi \rangle_H \forall \,\, v \in H,
$$
and $\|\varphi\|_{H'} = \|u_\varphi\|_H.$ In particular,
$$
(P)    \,\,\,\,\,\,\, \varphi(u_\varphi) = |u_\varphi|_H^2 = \|\varphi\|_{H'}^2.
$$
I would like to know if the vector $u_\varphi$ can be characterized by the property $(P)$, that is, if
$$
\varphi(w) = |w|_H^2 = \|\varphi\|_{H'}^2,
$$
then $w = u_\varphi$.

Notice that
$$
\|w - u_\varphi\|_H^2 = (|w|_H^2 - \langle w , u_\varphi \rangle_H ) + ( |u_\varphi|_H^2 - \langle w , u_\varphi \rangle_H) = (|w|_H^2 - \varphi(w) ) + ( \|\varphi\|_{H'}^2 - \varphi(w)) = 0 + 0 = 0.   
$$
Thus $\|w - u_\varphi\|_H = 0$ and $w = u_\varphi.$
